# Do I need to apply for a new ESTA when flying from a different airline?

Tags: air-travel, usa, customs-and-immigration, esta

When I made my ESTA application half a year ago (so within the 2 years), I flew from Japan. I had to enter the details about my Airline and from where I departed.

I'm going there again (this friday!!!), but flying from another country, and with another airline. I went to the ESTA web site, and checked my old application. It is still valid, and I updated the Hotel and state and city I'd be living in, but there was no way to update airline & country of departure.

Is it still valid?

Comment: I am in the same situation as you were in February. What happened at the airport? Were you able to travel with your old ESTA document? I would be pleased to hear about your expireances!

Comment: Hi Daniela! I had no problems at all. Turns out the airline information you fill into the ESTA forms (online thingy) was not a big deal at all. Don't ask me why they have it there in the first place. Wishing you a good time on your trip!

Comment: So, did the answer turn out to be correct? You didn't mark it as correct, as far as I can see.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Thank you for reminding me, it is now marked as correct.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No you don't need to apply for a new one if you change airlines or country of origin, the conditions that require you to reapply does not include change of airline or country of departure. You don't need to update your US address either.

From the [U.S. Customs and Border Protection website](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1072/~/about-the-electronic-system-for-travel-authorization-(esta)) (conditions that require you to reapply for ESTA):

> - You are issued a new passport,
> - You change your name (first and/or last)
> - You change your gender
> - Your country of citizenship changes
> - Your circumstances change, e.g., you are convicted of a crime of moral turpitude or you develop a contagious disease. Such a change may require you to get a visa to travel to the U.S. You must re-apply and your application must reflect the change in your circumstances or you may be denied entry upon arrival in the United States.

Comment: I'll bring my laptop and mark this as 'correct' when I've passed the airport ;-). 

Thanks for answering!

Comment: Make sure the laptop battery is fully charged. :)